# REST API containing POST and PUT/PATCH calling a compute server generating results files

Tags: rest, post, patch, put

The server application I'm implementing generates calculation results and stores these in result files in directories on the server. For example, customer/project/scenario/resultfiles. I want to design and implement a resilient REST implementation to retrieve the result files for display in the client browser, delete results files, customers etc and to create result files within a scenario for calculation parameters sent to the server. And possibly to do sensitivity analysis to generate result files within a scenario by varying calculation parameters.

I can use GET to retrieve these files using a URL with query string appname/?customerId=xxx&projectId=xxx etc And DELETE on the directory structure and files also using query strings. What I'm unclear about is the best REST approach to call functions implementing various calculations on the server.

Perhaps this should be a POST for the initial calculation in a scenario as this is creating the results files? Maybe a PUT or a PATCH for the sensitivity analysis or other partial recalculations as this is modifying results in an existing scenario?

There's a fair bit of online discussion about PUT vs PATCH vs POST used for database related activities. I could work up a REST approach based on what I've read for REST database interactions but if there's already standard practice on how to do calculations through a REST API I'd rather use that.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps this should be a POST for the initial calculation in a scenario as this is creating the results files? Maybe a PUT or a PATCH for the sensitivity analysis or other partial recalculations as this is modifying results in an existing scenario?

You can *always* just use POST.  If we were using HTML representations of resources to guide the client through the protocol, we'd be doing that by following links and submitting forms.  In HTML, submitting forms is limited to GET and POSt.

`PUT` and `PATCH` have more tightly constrained semantics than POST.  Specifically, they are methods that request that the server make its representation match the clients representation (for PUT, we send the entire replacement representation; for PATCH, we just send the changes made by the client).

Technically, there's nothing wrong with the server not accepting the offered edits as is:

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.  However, there is no guarantee that such a state change will be observable, since the target resource might be acted upon by other user agents in parallel, or might be subject to dynamic processing by the origin server, before any subsequent GET is received.  A successful response only implies that the user agent's intent was achieved at the time of its processing by the origin server.

So the server could accept the client's edits, and then immediately apply additional edits of its own.